# GUI Builder for Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, swt, eclipse-juno, gui-builder

Do you know any GUI builder for SWT, which is compatible with Eclipse Juno (4.2)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The correct entry site for the window builder would be http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/. The Google update sites still work, but the Window Builder is now an Eclipse project, and the main update sites are hosted at Eclipse. There you'll find also the link to the official update site for Juno (http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/release/R201206261200/4.2/) and a link for a ZIP download of the update site.

Answer (score 2):

Uh... this one was quick. Nevertheless I'll leave this question for everyone, who encounters the same problem, because as for now there are quite few or none official GUI builders for Juno.

I was misguided by the Window Builder download site (https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/download-wbpro), which does not include a link for Juno. Attempt to install the 3.7 version in Juno will fail.

However, it seems, that repository for Juno actually exists. The trick is to modify the repository URL:

Name: Window Builder Plugin
URL: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/4.2

Window Builder then installs correctly.